# Remove duplicate items from Listview that is filled by Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Listview that is filled by a sqlite query. One of the columns has duplicate entries (credit) and I would like to remove all duplicates in that column. I tried to do that at the sqlite query using the "distinct" method but it doesn't work.

Here's is the code

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM items " +
            "WHERE type = 'month' OR type = 'income' OR type = 'regular' OR type = 'credit' AND" +
            " month = " + monthOfYear + "  ORDER BY day ASC, _id ASC";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ItemsCursorAdapter adapter = new ItemsCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.row_layout, cursor, 0);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Used also changing the query to

```
SELECT * FROM items (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM items WHERE type = 'credit')
            "WHERE type = 'month' OR type = 'income' OR type = 'regular' OR type = 'credit' AND" +
            " month = " + monthOfYear + "  ORDER BY day ASC, _id ASC
```

Comment: Try `group by your_column` in your query for removing the duplicates.

Comment: It doesn't work since every entry has an unique _id, so it displays all the entries

Comment: changes in your adapter so if you put that adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in the comment above you can change your query as:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM items " +
            "WHERE type = 'month' OR type = 'income' OR type = 'regular' OR type = 'credit' AND" +
            " month = " + monthOfYear + " GROUP by _id ORDER BY day ASC, _id ASC";
```

In the Above query, you can see I've used the `_id` column for grouping the entries and it works great.

Comment: It doesn't work since every entry has an unique _id, so it displays all the entries

Comment: @JoseBorges So why are they duplicate? there has to be a value which is same for some 
rows by which you are terming them as duplicate, just use that in place of _id.

Comment: some of the rows have duplicate value but there is only one value that I want to group which is "credit"

Comment: "credit" is in some rows, the column is "type" and there are other rows that have also duplicate entries,but those I don't want to group them

Comment: @joseborges If your database isn't so large, create a separate column for distinct entries.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

I have same problem, which is you have facing now, I had fixed it by following way.

Code for MainActivity.java file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listview;
    List<String> subject_list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        subject_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        subject_list.add("ONE");
        subject_list.add("TWO");
        subject_list.add("THREE");
        subject_list.add("FOUR");
        subject_list.add("FIVE");
        subject_list.add("SIX");
        subject_list.add("SEVEN");
        subject_list.add("EIGHT");
        subject_list.add("NINE");
        subject_list.add("TEN");
        subject_list.add("THREE");
        subject_list.add("FOUR");
        subject_list.add("FIVE");
        subject_list.add("THREE");
        subject_list.add("FOUR");
        subject_list.add("FIVE");
        subject_list.add("THREE");
        subject_list.add("FOUR");
        subject_list.add("FIVE");

        //Deleting Same entries

        HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
        hashSet.addAll(subject_list);
        subject_list.clear();
        subject_list.addAll(hashSet);

        //Alphabetic sorting.
        Collections.sort(subject_list);

        arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subject_list);

        listview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);

    }
}
```